# verbose displayed halfly over text mode booting

Tags: boot, display, text-mode

I tried to boot my Ubuntu into text mode with verbosity enabled, this is what I configured in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text init=/sbin/init --verbose vga=791"
```

then `update-grub` and `reboot`.
It turned out that, however, the first half of the booting output no verbose, after about 14 seconds the next half showed up, and very soon the login come out.

This is the output at the beginning of the verbose displaying:

```
[   12.902147] init: mounted-tmp state changed from waiting to starting
[   12.902333] init: Handling starting event
[   12.902786] init: mounted-tmp state changed from starting to pre-start
[   12.902975] init: mounted-tmp state changed from pre-start to spawned
[   12.914907] init: mounted-tmp main process (360)
[   12.915188] init: mounted-tmp state changed from spawned to post-start
[   12.919397] init: mounted-tmp state changed from post-start to running
[   12.921018] init: Handling started event
[   12.932362] init: Handling module-device-added event
[   12.993888] init: Handling acpi-device-added event
[   13.005511] init: Handling usb-device-added event
[   13.024811] init: Handling acpi-device-added event
[   13.039924] init: Handling acpi-device-added event
[   13.096252] init: Handling acpi-device-added event
[   13.108895] init: Handling acpi-device-added event
[   13.109732] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

I also checked that the output messages was indeed complete in the log file `/var/log/dmesg`.

I really want to see the complete verbose display scrolling over booting, does any one have a trick?

PS:

- guest OS: Ubuntu LTS 12.04
- host OS: Windows 7
- Using Oracle VirtualBox 4.1.18